My App crashes run-time occasionally when I use AVFoundation and related code
I am developing an app for Vehicle owners with a built-in map navigation feature with voice navigation support. The app works fine without voice navigation but when I use voice navigation it occasionally crashes and it crashes while voice navigation is not in progress.
What makes it impossible to diagnose is that even though it crashed 10 times on the TestFlight, I don't see any crash reports in 'Apple Connect'. I tried running it in a simulator and it didn't crash there! but on a real device, when I drive with the app navigating me it crashes abruptly after a few minutes and it's not while the voice navigation is speaking! I also ran the app without AVFoundation and it did not crash then. So I am 100% sure it is something with this AVFoundation framework.
If anyone can help find the problem in my following code it would be really helpful.
//
//  DirectionsView.swift
//  Map
//
//  Created by saj panchal on 2023-12-10.
//

import SwiftUI
///framework to record, playback and stream parsing. Also provides interfaces to manage audio sessions
//import AudioToolbox
///framework that contains tasks to inspect, play, capture and process the audio video content.
import AVFoundation
///a view responsible to show the direction signs along with the instruction text on top of the screen while navigating.
struct DirectionHeaderView: View {
    ///environment variable to get the color mode of the phone
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var bgMode: ColorScheme
    ///variable that stores the image name for various direction signs.
    var directionSign: String?
    ///stores distance from the next step in string format.
    var nextStepDistance: String
    ///stores the instruction string.
    var instruction: String
    ///flag that is bound to MapSwiftUI. it is set when user taps on this view to see the expanded directions list view.
    @Binding var showDirectionsList: Bool
    @Binding var height: CGFloat
    ///locationDataManager is an instance of a class that has a delegate of LocationManager and its methods.
    @StateObject var locationDataManager: LocationDataManager
    ///AVSpeechSynthesizer class is responsible to create a synthesized speech from text utterances. it also play, pause or stop the speech based on the requirements.
    @State private var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    ///AVAudioSession is responsible to create an audio session sharedInstance that acts as a mediator between this app and the phone os. And, it creates an audio session based on the preferences.
    @State private var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    @State private var lastInstruction: String = ""
    @State private var utteranceDistance: String = ""
    @State private var isStepExited = false
    @State private var range = 20.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ///enclosing the directions and instruction view in horizontal stack.
            HStack {
                ///shows direction sign and next step distance below it.
                VStack {
                    ///if directionSign is not empty show the image.
                    if let directionSign = directionSign {
                        Image(systemName: directionSign)
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.black)
                            .padding(.top, 5)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                        
                    }
                    ///show the distance from next step
                    if !instruction.contains("Re-calculating the route...") {
                        Text("\(nextStepDistance)")
                            .padding(.bottom, 5)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .fontWeight(.black)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color(AppColors.invertRed.rawValue))
                            .onChange(of: nextStepDistance) {
                                let distance = getDistanceInNumber(distance: nextStepDistance)
                            
                                if distance <= range && !isStepExited {
                                    startVoiceNavigation(with: instruction)
                                    isStepExited = true
                                }
                                
                            }
                    }
                    
                }
                ///add a space between directions and instruction stacks.
                Spacer()
                    ///showing the instruction in a text format
                    Text(instruction)
                    .onAppear {
                        print("instruction Appear")
                        isStepExited = false
                        ///set the utteranceDistance by the updated next step distance on appear of instruction text
                        utteranceDistance = nextStepDistance
                         range = nextStepRange(distance: utteranceDistance)
                        print("Step range: \( range), Speed: \(locationDataManager.speed)")
                        ///start voice navigation with the utterance.
                        startVoiceNavigation(with: "In \(utteranceDistance), \(instruction)")
                    }
                    .onChange(of: instruction) {
                        print("On change of instruction")
                        isStepExited = false
                        ///set the utteranceDistance by the updated next step distance on update of instruction text
                        utteranceDistance = nextStepDistance
                        range = nextStepRange(distance: utteranceDistance)
                        print("Step range: \( range), Speed: \(locationDataManager.speed)")
                        startVoiceNavigation(with: "In \(utteranceDistance), \(instruction)")
                    }
                        .padding(10)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                ///add a spacer to the right of the instruction view.
                Spacer()
            }
            if !showDirectionsList {
                ExpandViewSymbol()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("directionview appeared")
           // setupAudioSession()
     
        }
        
        .padding(.horizontal,10)
        ///apply the black gradient to entire view.
        .background(bgMode == .dark ? Color.black.gradient : Color.white.gradient)
    }
    func startVoiceNavigation(with utterance: String) {
       ///if instruction is empty return the function call
        if instruction.isEmpty || utterance.isEmpty {
            print("instruction empty")
            return
        }
        if instruction.contains("Re-calculating the route...") {
            synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
            return
        }
        ///create a speech utterance instance from utterance string
        let thisUttarance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: utterance)
        ///save the current instruction as last received instruction
        lastInstruction = instruction
       ///making sure the audio session is set the a given category and options
        if audioSession.category == .playback && audioSession.categoryOptions == .mixWithOthers {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                ///command synthesizer to speak the utterance
                synthesizer.speak(thisUttarance)
                print("Speaking...\(synthesizer.isSpeaking) \(instruction)")
            }
        }
        ///if audio session is not configured.
        else {
            ///setup the audio session
            setupAudioSession()
            ///command the synthesizer to speak.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                synthesizer.speak(thisUttarance)
            }
            print("Speaking again...")
        }
    }
    
    func setupAudioSession() {
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            print("audio session is created.")
        }
        catch {
            print("error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func nextStepRange(distance: String) -> Double {
        var thisStepDistance = getDistanceInNumber(distance: distance)

        if thisStepDistance != 0 {
            switch thisStepDistance {
            case 0...200:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return thisStepDistance/1.5
                }
                else {
                    return thisStepDistance/2
                }
            case 201...300:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return 120
                }
                else {
                    return 100
                }
            case 301...500:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return 150
                }
                else {
                    return 125
                }
            case 501...1000:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return 250
                }
                else {
                    return 200
                }
            case 1001...10000:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return 250
                }
                else {
                    return 200
                }
            
            default:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return 250
                }
                else {
                    return  200
                }
              
            }
        }
      
        return 200
    }
    func getDistanceInNumber(distance: String) -> Double {
        var thisStepDistance = 0.0
        if distance.contains("km") {
            let stepDistanceSplits = distance.split(separator: " ")
            let stepDistanceText = String(stepDistanceSplits[0])
            if let dist = Double(stepDistanceText) {
                thisStepDistance = dist * 1000
            }
          
        }
        else {
            var stepDistanceSplits = distance.split(separator: " ")
            var stepDistanceText = String(stepDistanceSplits[0])
            if let dist = Double(stepDistanceText) {
                thisStepDistance = dist               
            }
        }
        print("Converted number: \(thisStepDistance)")
        return thisStepDistance
    }
}

#Preview {
    DirectionHeaderView(directionSign: "", nextStepDistance: "", instruction: "", showDirectionsList: .constant(false), height: .constant(0), locationDataManager: LocationDataManager())
}

New file added to the project (Class SpeechViewModel):
import AVFoundation

class SpeechViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    @Published var isSpeaking = false
    @Published var isFinished = false
    @Published var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    @Published var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("speech view init")
        synthesizer.delegate = self
        self.setupAudioSession()
      
       
    }

    deinit {
        synthesizer.delegate = nil
        print("speech view deinit")
        do {
            try self.audioSession.setActive(false)
          print("audio session inactive")
        }
        catch {
            print("error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func speak(_ utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }
    func setupAudioSession() {
        do {
            try self.audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
            try self.audioSession.setActive(true)
            print("audio session is created.")
        }
        catch {
            print("error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    // MARK: AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate
    internal func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didStart utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("is speaking")
        self.isSpeaking = true
        self.isFinished = false
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("finsihed speaking")
        self.isSpeaking = false
        self.isFinished = true
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didPause utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("paused speaking")
        self.isSpeaking = false
        self.isFinished = false
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didCancel utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("canceled speaking")
        self.isSpeaking = false
        self.isFinished = false
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didContinue utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print(utterance, "continue speaking")
        self.isFinished = false
        self.isSpeaking = true
    }
    
   
}

Updated DirectionsHeader view:
    //
//  DirectionsView.swift
//  Map
//
//  Created by saj panchal on 2023-12-10.
//

import SwiftUI
///framework to record, playback and stream parsing. Also provides interfaces to manage audio sessions
//import AudioToolbox
///framework that contains tasks to inspect, play, capture and process the audio video content.
import AVFoundation
///a view responsible to show the direction signs along with the instruction text on top of the screen while navigating.
struct DirectionHeaderView: View {
    ///environment variable to get the color mode of the phone
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var bgMode: ColorScheme
    ///variable that stores the image name for various direction signs.
    var directionSign: String?
    ///stores distance from the next step in string format.
    var nextStepDistance: String
    ///stores the instruction string.
    var instruction: String
    ///flag that is bound to MapSwiftUI. it is set when user taps on this view to see the expanded directions list view.
    @Binding var showDirectionsList: Bool
    @Binding var height: CGFloat
    ///locationDataManager is an instance of a class that has a delegate of LocationManager and its methods.
    @StateObject var locationDataManager: LocationDataManager
    ///AVSpeechSynthesizer class is responsible to create a synthesized speech from text utterances. it also play, pause or stop the speech based on the requirements.
   // @State private var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    ///AVAudioSession is responsible to create an audio session sharedInstance that acts as a mediator between this app and the phone os. And, it creates an audio session based on the preferences.
    //@State private var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    @StateObject private var speechVm = SpeechViewModel()
    @State private var lastInstruction: String = ""
    @State private var utteranceDistance: String = ""
    @State private var isStepExited = false
    @State private var range = 20.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ///enclosing the directions and instruction view in horizontal stack.
            HStack {
                ///shows direction sign and next step distance below it.
                VStack {
                    ///if directionSign is not empty show the image.
                    if let directionSign = directionSign {
                        Image(systemName: directionSign)
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.black)
                            .padding(.top, 5)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                        
                    }
                    ///show the distance from next step
                    if !instruction.contains("Re-calculating the route...") {
                        Text("\(nextStepDistance)")
                            .padding(.bottom, 5)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .fontWeight(.black)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color(AppColors.invertRed.rawValue))
                            .onChange(of: nextStepDistance) {
                                let distance = getDistanceInNumber(distance: nextStepDistance)
                            
                                if distance <= range && !isStepExited {
                                    startVoiceNavigation(with: instruction)
                                    isStepExited = true
                                }
                                
                            }
                    }
                    
                }
                ///add a space between directions and instruction stacks.
                Spacer()
                    ///showing the instruction in a text format
                    Text(instruction)
                    .onAppear {
                        print("instruction Appear")
                        isStepExited = false
                        ///set the utteranceDistance by the updated next step distance on appear of instruction text
                        utteranceDistance = nextStepDistance
                         range = nextStepRange(distance: utteranceDistance)
                        print("Step range: \( range), Speed: \(locationDataManager.speed)")
                        ///start voice navigation with the utterance.
                        startVoiceNavigation(with: "In \(utteranceDistance), \(instruction)")
                    }
                    .onChange(of: instruction) {
                        print("On change of instruction")
                        isStepExited = false
                        ///set the utteranceDistance by the updated next step distance on update of instruction text
                        utteranceDistance = nextStepDistance
                        range = nextStepRange(distance: utteranceDistance)
                        print("Step range: \( range), Speed: \(locationDataManager.speed)")
                        startVoiceNavigation(with: "In \(utteranceDistance), \(instruction)")
                    }
                        .padding(10)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                ///add a spacer to the right of the instruction view.
                Spacer()
            }
            if !showDirectionsList {
                ExpandViewSymbol()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("directionview appeared")
           // setupAudioSession()
     
        }
        
        .padding(.horizontal,10)
        ///apply the black gradient to entire view.
        .background(bgMode == .dark ? Color.black.gradient : Color.white.gradient)
    }
    func startVoiceNavigation(with utterance: String) {
       ///if instruction is empty return the function call
        if instruction.isEmpty || utterance.isEmpty {
            print("instruction empty")
            return
        }
        if instruction.contains("Re-calculating the route...") {
            speechVm.synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
            return
        }
        ///create a speech utterance instance from utterance string
        let thisUttarance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: utterance)
        ///save the current instruction as last received instruction
        lastInstruction = instruction
       ///making sure the audio session is set the a given category and options
        if speechVm.audioSession.category == .playback && speechVm.audioSession.categoryOptions == .mixWithOthers {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                ///command synthesizer to speak the utterance
                speechVm.synthesizer.speak(thisUttarance)
                print("Speaking...\(speechVm.synthesizer.isSpeaking) \(instruction)")
            }
        }
        ///if audio session is not configured.
        else {
            ///setup the audio session
            speechVm.setupAudioSession()
            ///command the synthesizer to speak.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                speechVm.synthesizer.speak(thisUttarance)
            }
            print("Speaking again...")
        }
    }
    
//    func setupAudioSession() {
//        do {
//            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
//            try audioSession.setActive(true)
//            print("audio session is created.")
//        }
//        catch {
//            print("error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
//        }
//    }
    
    func nextStepRange(distance: String) -> Double {
        let thisStepDistance = getDistanceInNumber(distance: distance)

        if thisStepDistance != 0 {
            switch thisStepDistance {
            case 0...200:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return thisStepDistance/1.5
                }
                else {
                    return thisStepDistance/2
                }
            case 201...300:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return 120
                }
                else {
                    return 100
                }
            case 301...500:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return 150
                }
                else {
                    return 125
                }
            case 501...1000:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return 250
                }
                else {
                    return 200
                }
            case 1001...10000:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return 250
                }
                else {
                    return 200
                }
            
            default:
                if locationDataManager.speed >= 90 {
                    return 250
                }
                else {
                    return  200
                }
              
            }
        }
      
        return 200
    }
    func getDistanceInNumber(distance: String) -> Double {
        var thisStepDistance = 0.0
        if distance.contains("km") {
            let stepDistanceSplits = distance.split(separator: " ")
            let stepDistanceText = String(stepDistanceSplits[0])
            if let dist = Double(stepDistanceText) {
                thisStepDistance = dist * 1000
            }
          
        }
        else {
            let stepDistanceSplits = distance.split(separator: " ")
            var stepDistanceText = String(stepDistanceSplits[0])
            if let dist = Double(stepDistanceText) {
                thisStepDistance = dist               
            }
        }
        print("Converted number: \(thisStepDistance)")
        return thisStepDistance
    }
}

#Preview {
    DirectionHeaderView(directionSign: "", nextStepDistance: "", instruction: "", showDirectionsList: .constant(false), height: .constant(0), locationDataManager: LocationDataManager())
}


synthesizer and audioSession declarations don’t look right

can you explain further?

@State is for structs that are a source of truth. sharedInstance looks like a shared object (not a source of truth) so it is @ObservedObject

Well I was using that attribute before and it was getting the audiosession instance deallocated unexpectedly!

Your singleton must have a mistake

I have made some changes. First, I have added a new file with an observable class SpeechViewModel as a delegate to AVSpeechSynthesizer to handle audio sessions and speech synthesizer tasks. Second, I am instantiating this class and setting it as @StateObject to directionsView. check the updated codes above for more details.

I checked, you probably shouldn't have @Published for audioSession and synthesizer.

Thanks, Malcolm. I think it helped reduce the crashes and improved app performance. Some other issues related to Metal API (which I am not using) were causing the crashes, too. I dealt with that, and so far, I don't get crashes anymore.
